# Get y position of timeline animated movieclip AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, actionscript, tween

I have a timeline animated movieclip (strip1) which animates in a endless loop.

Question: During the loop animation all I want to do is call strip1 on the main timeline get the current y value of the tween and have it animate to a certain Y position.

Is that possible?

Thanks,
C

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. If it's a tween, isn't it already animating?

Comment: Based off what @Amy mentioned, you should pick one method for animation and stick to that. Mixing them doesn't work well - once you modify the position of something with ActionScript, timeline animation for that object is lost.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to move that "animation" around the canvas as an independent object?, if so, then you should cut and paste the animation on that timeline into a new movieclip, drop it in the canvas again and give an instance name. You can control it's Y position with McInstance.y

Hope this helps.

CT